# Сломана панель wysiwyg редактора в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, очередь-проверок, редактор

При попытке отредактировать вопрос из очереди проверок появляется редактор без панели(с пустой панелью):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка наблюдается только в очереди проверок.
При правке вопросов из поиска редактор работает корректно.

На странице в консоле следующая ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'creationCallbacks' of undefined
    at Object.t [as init] (full.ru.js?v=60cf09f7dc42:4)
    at Object.i [as init] (full.ru.js?v=60cf09f7dc42:5)
    at VM70 first-posts:410
    at Array.<anonymous> (stub.ru.js?v=4fc3263c7f6c:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.e.(anonymous function) [as resolve] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:29192)
```

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изменение, которое привело к ошибке, откатили. На данный момент редактор в очереди проверок работает корректно.